# alert occurs before visibility hidden in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these javascript codes, they work fine on first load, but if I try it after a failed login attempt (when the red texts are visible), it doesn't turn them into hidden and alerts instantly.

although *alert()* is at the bottom of the code, it is executed before    *$('.invalid-feed').css('visibility', 'hidden');*

why is that?

[**http://jsfiddle.net/jzpdLv0h/19**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzpdLv0h/20/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#myButton").click(function(){


    $('.invalid-feed').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    var status = 'success';


    var mySentence1 = $('#firstName').val();
    if (mySentence1 === "")
    {
      $('.invalid-feed#invalid1').css('visibility', 'visible');
      status = 'error';
    }

var mySentence2 = $('#lastName').val();
if (mySentence2 === "")
{
  $('.invalid-feed#invalid2').css('visibility', 'visible');
  status = 'error';
}

var mySentence3 = $('#email').val();
if (mySentence3 === "")
{   
  $('.invalid-feed#invalid3').css('visibility', 'visible');
  status = 'error';
}

if (status == 'success')
{
    alert("success");
}

  });

});
```

Comment: It's possible the browser takes some time to update. Try `setTimeout(function() { alert("Success"); }, 20);` instead.

Comment: @soktinpk I know it works with setTimeout, ........ just wondering why it does not hide the warnings first and then alert without setTimeout

Comment: What red lights? You mean the red warning text? And what login, your fiddle doesn't have any kind of login simulation

Comment: It takes some time to update the DOM rendering and such, while `alert` will block. In general, it is probably not the best idea to use "alerts" for this reason except when you need to block (for example, when the user is about to leave the page). Alert has other undesirable effects such as, on mobile, being unable to do anything else until the alert is closed, and generally being unable to interact with anything until the alert message is closed.

Comment: @soktinpk thank you very much for the info!

Comment: JS is single threaded. That means any DOM updates, including style changes, have to be done after any currently running javascript. As soktinpk says `alert` blocks so the browser cannot update the DOM until the `alert` is closed

Comment: Please, provide with a sequence of input that generates the undesired effect. I'm testing your jsfiddle and is working alright on my browser.

Comment: @D.Smania you're probably using firefox or edge, OP is probably using something other than firefox or edge ... i.e. in firefox or edge, this works as OP wants as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although alert() is at the bottom of the code, it is executed before $('.invalid-feed').css('visibility', 'hidden');

I believe it's because jQuery's transition of an element from 'visible' to 'hidden' has a default duration of 400ms, so as it proceeds, the Javascript parser continues with the rest of the script, and arrives at and implements the alert() before the 400ms has elapsed.

soktinpk's answer is helpful, btw.